# why does the nginx passive health check configuration is not working?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, artifactory, health-check

I'm using Nginx OSS *nginx/1.20.1* version as a reverse proxy and load balancer. Behind the load balancer, there are two servers available where the jfrog artifactory web app service has been running.

I would like to configure the Nginx in such a way that whenever the web app service gets down, the Nginx should stop sending the request to the particular server.

For this purpose, I have added the [passive health check](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/) parameters(*fail_timeout=900s*) in the conf file

```
upstream artifactory {
    server 172.1.1.1:8082  fail_timeout=900s;
    server 172.1.1.2:8082  fail_timeout=900s;
}

upstream artifactory-direct {
    server 172.1.1.1:8081  fail_timeout=900s;
    server 172.1.1.2:8081  fail_timeout=900s;
}

server {
    listen 80  default_server;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxxx.net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.net;
    return 301 https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.net$request_uri;

}
```

Then I have stopped the web service in one of the upstream servers and checked the Nginx error log, it is redirecting the request to both the upstream servers. Ideally, it should mark one of the servers as "unavailable" but it is doing like that. Could someone help with this, please?

Attached the [nginx config files](https://gist.github.com/navinprasadk/c3a4141897ed94e2793c718f591b975b)

Comment: why do you configure the `fail_timeout` to 900s? This means to stop nginx to send traffic to this server it has to be down for at least! 900s (15min). That is a pretty long time. Change the time to something like 5 sec and NGINX will use the other server to send the traffic to. And where is your `proxy_pass` configuration? Would you mind sharing the whole NGINX configuration?

Comment: Hello Timo Stark, Thank you for responding. Initially, I tried with 30 secs, I'm not sure the Nginx is redirecting to another upstream. So, increased the timeout. I have attached the Nginx config file. Can you please check once?

Comment: Yes, Nginx redirects a request to another upstream server as soon as previous one failed to handle it. but such behavior is not related to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an expected behavior with Nginx open-source version. You can find more details about this on [this page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/?_bt=573371260709&_bk=&_bm=&_bn=g&_bg=134448916520&gclid=Cj0KCQiAmKiQBhClARIsAKtSj-m7IwjN3Y6AeJt34ycAc3B6uY4eMLyyU_0m3aRbueJTewKZ0Mlzw00aAge5EALw_wcB)

As an alternate: you can automate the process of validating the backend (Artifactory) availability with a simple [health check REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemHealthPing) and update the Nginx configuration if there is an issue. Keep running the script in a crontab

Answer (score 0):

Here's how Nginx works with the directive [`fail_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#fail_timeout), assume `fail_timeout` is set to `Td` :

- if an upstream server (say `U0`) fails to process and respond with number of requests (specified by `max_fails`) in `Td` seconds, Nginx will mark `U0` as *unavailable* at the time `T0`.
- From here, Nginx temporarily passes new requests to other upstream servers except `U0` for `Td` seconds, until the timeout happenes (at the time `T0 + Td`), then Nginx retries connecting and sending a request to `U0`:

  - if `U0` is recovered and able to handle request, then mark it as *active*
  - otherwise Nginx repeats the same behavior, distributes requests to other upstream servers except `U0` until next timeout event.

To see whether Nginx marks any upstream server as *unavailable*, make sure the [logging level](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html?#error_log) is *warn* (or below that e.g. *info*, *debug*) so Nginx will dump appropriate detail to error log.